# UML for GWT project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, plugins, uml

I just thinking... Is there a UML (the reverse engeneering) for GWT projecting in Eclipse to simplify the developing process?
I mean the thing as the NetBeans has?

Any useful comments are appreciated

Andrew

Comment: Emm... what you mean? There is no UML for GWT or something?

Answer (score 0):

You only have java reverse engineering features inside the Eclipse UML plugins.

Comment: well, I am not sure I have any uml plugin for eclipse installed. But I need the plugin work for  GWT projects... Is there some useful plugin in this direction? I mean something like this developing style as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31BnR2AKazM but with eclipse and for gwt projects?

Comment: So did you find any such plugin for eclispe? Or did you use some separate tool itself to do the same job, `reverse engineering UML diagram`. Suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

there's [UIBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) to simplify the layout; please give a more detailed example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I have downloaded eclipse. then I installed gwt on it... Sure I have UI editor to develope GWT GUI but I am wondering how to make GWT BL with UML? I used to use NetBeans 6.5.1 UML plugin but I couldn't find anything in this direction for GWT.